# POST and PUT Requests not working from Phalcon website to Prestashop web service

Tags: php, xml, prestashop, phalcon

I'm facing an issue since a while now while trying to send POST or PUT request to Prestashop Webservice from another website developed with PHP framework Phalcon.
Here is the code i'm using to initialize my provider following this example https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Http/Client :

```
$uriCustomer = $this->config->application->storeAPIUrl;

       // get available provider Curl or Stream
       try {
           $provider = Request::getProvider();
       } catch (Exception $e) {
       }

       $provider->header->set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
       $provider->header->set('Accept', '*/*');
```

Here is the code i'm using to send the request :

```
$response = $provider->post(
            $uriCustomer.'/customers',
            [
                'body'        => $xml
            ]
        );

        var_dump($xml);
        dump($response->body);exit();
```

And here are the two xml i've tried to send (the first one being the one returned by the api when i perform a get request) :

```
$xmlBlank = '<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<customer>
<id_default_group xlink:href="http://local.loveinlive-store.com/api/groups/3"><![CDATA[3]]></id_default_group>
<id_lang xlink:href="http://local.loveinlive-store.com/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[1]]></id_lang>
<newsletter_date_add><![CDATA[0000-00-00 00:00:00]]></newsletter_date_add>
<ip_registration_newsletter></ip_registration_newsletter>
<last_passwd_gen><![CDATA[2019-12-11 10:09:00]]></last_passwd_gen>
<secure_key><![CDATA[7edcb15d69ef0bf455e706857d63bf97]]></secure_key>
<deleted><![CDATA[0]]></deleted>
<passwd><![CDATA[$fjezhngfgr]]></passwd>
<lastname><![CDATA[weggs]]></lastname>
<firstname><![CDATA[loic]]></firstname>
<email><![CDATA[loic@weggs.fr]]></email>
<id_gender><![CDATA[1]]></id_gender>
<birthday><![CDATA[0000-00-00]]></birthday>
<newsletter><![CDATA[0]]></newsletter>
<optin><![CDATA[0]]></optin>
<website></website>
<company></company>
<siret></siret>
<ape></ape>
<outstanding_allow_amount><![CDATA[0.000000]]></outstanding_allow_amount>
<show_public_prices><![CDATA[0]]></show_public_prices>
<id_risk><![CDATA[0]]></id_risk>
<max_payment_days><![CDATA[0]]></max_payment_days>
<active><![CDATA[1]]></active>
<note></note>
<is_guest><![CDATA[0]]></is_guest>
<id_shop><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop>
<id_shop_group><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop_group>
<date_add><![CDATA[2019-12-11 16:09:00]]></date_add>
<date_upd><![CDATA[2019-12-11 16:09:00]]></date_upd>
<reset_password_token></reset_password_token>
<reset_password_validity><![CDATA[0000-00-00 00:00:00]]></reset_password_validity>
<associations>
<groups nodeType="group" api="groups">
<group xlink:href="http://local.loveinlive-store.com/api/groups/3">
<id><![CDATA[3]]></id>
</group>
</groups>
</associations>
</customer>
</prestashop>';
```

```
$xml ='<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <customer>
                <id_default_group xlink:href="http://local.loveinlive-store.com/api/groups/3">3</id_default_group>
                <id_lang xlink:href="http://local.loveinlive-store.com/api/languages/1">1</id_lang>
                <newsletter_date_add></newsletter_date_add>
                <ip_registration_newsletter></ip_registration_newsletter>
                <last_passwd_gen></last_passwd_gen>
                <secure_key></secure_key>
                <deleted></deleted>
                <passwd>testtest</passwd>
                <lastname>test</lastname>
                <firstname>test</firstname>
                <email>test@test.fr</email>
                <id_gender>1</id_gender>
                <birthday></birthday>
                <newsletter></newsletter>
                <optin></optin>
                <website></website>
                <company></company>
                <siret></siret>
                <ape></ape>
                <outstanding_allow_amount></outstanding_allow_amount>
                <show_public_prices></show_public_prices>
                <id_risk></id_risk>
                <max_payment_days></max_payment_days>
                <active>1</active>
                <note></note>
                <is_guest></is_guest>
                <id_shop>1</id_shop>
                <id_shop_group>1</id_shop_group>
                <date_add></date_add>
                <date_upd></date_upd>
                <reset_password_token></reset_password_token>
                <reset_password_validity></reset_password_validity>
                <associations>
                    <groups nodeType="group" api="groups">
                        <group xlink:href="http://local.loveinlive-store.com/api/groups/3">
                            <id>3</id>
                        </group>
                    </groups>
                </associations>
            </customer>
        </prestashop>';
```

The request works perfectly when using Postman but from my application I keep getting this error when dumping my response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<errors>
<error>
<code><![CDATA[3]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[[PHP Warning #2] SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found (/home/loic/web/loveinlives ▶
</error>
<error>
<code><![CDATA[3]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[[PHP Warning #2] SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): %3Cprestashop+xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%3E%3C (/home/loic ▶
</error>
<error>
<code><![CDATA[3]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[[PHP Warning #2] SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ (/home/loic/web/loveinlivestore/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php, line 1497)]]></m ▶
</error>
<error>
<code><![CDATA[127]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[XML error : String could not be parsed as XML
XML length : 1727
Original XML : %3Cprestashop+xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%3E%3Ccustomer%3E%3Cid_default_group+xlink%3Ahref%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Floc ▶
</error>
</errors>
</prestashop>
```

I know that that kind of issues has already been reported but none of the solutions mentioned have solved my issue so any help would be welcome

Edit: 
I finally succeed to make it work. I was following the code shown here https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Http/Client . But actually, the request' body was not expected to be pass in an array of parameters. Hence, the correction was simply to change:

```
$response = $provider->post(
            $uriCustomer.'/customers',
            [
                'body'        => $xml
            ]
        );
```

For

```
$response = $provider->post($uriCustomer.'/customers',
            $xml
        );
```

Which finally gives the following method :

```
public function postCustomerPersonalDatas($user) {

        // Uri of Prestashop Api formatted like http://API_KEY@prestashopUrl.com/api
        $uriCustomer = $this->config->application->storeAPIUrl;

        // get available provider Curl or Stream
        try {
            $provider = Request::getProvider();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throwException($e);
        }

        // Return a string containing a formatted customer that you can then fill as you want
        $customerModel = $provider->get($uriCustomer.'/customers?schema=blank'
        );

//        Turn the returned string into XML so you can easily edit it
        $customerModel = new \SimpleXMLElement($customerModel->body);

//       Call a function that return the datas I need
        $customerDatas = $this->getCustomerPersonalDatas($user);

//      Edit the formatted xml with wanted datas
        $customerXML = $customerModel;
        $customerXML->customer[0]->id_customer_lil = $customerDatas['id_customer_lil'];
        $customerXML->customer[0]->passwd = $customerDatas['passwd'];
        $customerXML->customer[0]->email = $customerDatas['email'];
        $customerXML->customer[0]->id_gender = $customerDatas['id_gender'];
        $customerXML->customer[0]->birthday = $customerDatas['birthday'];
        $customerXML->customer[0]->lastname = strval($customerDatas['id_customer_lil']).'lastnamelil';
        $customerXML->customer[0]->firstname = strval($customerDatas['id_customer_lil']).'firstnamelil';

//        Send the request using asXML() function as Prestashop webservice expect to receive a string
        try{
            $response = $provider->post($uriCustomer.'/customers',
                $customerXML->asXML()
            );
            return 'Success on store registration';
        } catch (\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
            return $e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please can you share the phalcon code sample that handles the request? Does the api takes care of CORS?

Comment: I finally managed to make it work but thank you for your time The Oracle

Comment: Great! Mavoli Please can you share your solution to the problem as answer to this question? Thanks

Comment: I made an edit with full solution. I did not get any issue regarding CORS policy so I guess Prestashop Webservices handles it